# Nexus Mod Manager not finding my games on my external hard drive

Tags: mods, nexus-mod-manager

I Installed 2 new games onto my E Drive (which is external).

Nexus Mod Manager only tries to find them on my C drive although all of my games are on my E drive. When I try to do it myself, it says that I am missing the .exe, but I am not.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what you tell, I believe the automatic game-search of the mod manager isn't browsing your E-drive. I recommend manually inputting the .exe directory in the appropriate field.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using system links (like shortcuts). Try creating a directory system link on your C drive that points to the appropriate folder on your E drive.